# Is there a keyboard shortcut for the AC button on Yosemite calculator?

Tags: keyboard, macos

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will trigger the AC button on the OS X Yosemite calculator? Escape key triggers the Clear (C), but hitting escape again does NOT trigger the AC. Only a mouse click does.

[image: Calculator AC button]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my MacBook Pro, AC/All Clear can be achieved by **fn** + **esc**.

Answer (score 1):

On a wired extended keyboard, it's the 'square with an X in it' above 7.   <kbd>⌧</kbd>

[image]

I don't know where it is on a laptop or short keyboard.